# Hook into GHC runtime system

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, runtime, transactional-memory

I have been looking at how transactional memory is implemented in Haskell, and I am not sure I understand how the STM operations exposed to the programmer hook into the runtime system functions written in C.  In `ghc/libraries/base/GHC/Conc/Sync.hs` of the git repo, I see the following definitions:

```
-- |A monad supporting atomic memory transactions.
newtype STM a = STM (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
            deriving Typeable

-- |Shared memory locations that support atomic memory transactions.
data TVar a = TVar (TVar# RealWorld a)
          deriving Typeable

-- |Create a new TVar holding a value supplied
newTVar :: a -> STM (TVar a)
newTVar val = STM $ \s1# ->
    case newTVar# val s1# of
         (# s2#, tvar# #) -> (# s2#, TVar tvar# #)
```

Then in `ghc/rts/PrimOps.cmm`, I see the following C-- definition:

```
stg_newTVarzh (P_ init){
  W_ tv;

  ALLOC_PRIM_P (SIZEOF_StgTVar, stg_newTVarzh, init);

  tv = Hp - SIZEOF_StgTVar + WDS(1);
  SET_HDR (tv, stg_TVAR_DIRTY_info, CCCS);

  StgTVar_current_value(tv) = init;
  StgTVar_first_watch_queue_entry(tv) = stg_END_STM_WATCH_QUEUE_closure;
  StgTVar_num_updates(tv) = 0;

  return (tv);
}
```

My questions:

1. What does the first and last `#` mean in `(# s2#, TVar tvar# #)`.  I've read before that putting a `#` after a variable is just a naming convention indicating something is unboxed, but what does it mean when it is by itself?
2. How do we get from `newTVar#` to `stg_newTVarzh`?  It seems like I am missing another definition between these two.  Does the compiler rewrite `newTVar#` into a call to the C-- function listed?
3. What are `P_` and `W_` in the C-- code?

I have only been able to find one other occurrence of `newTVar#` in `ghc/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp`

```
primop  NewTVarOp "newTVar#" GenPrimOp
   a
    -> State# s -> (# State# s, TVar# s a #)
 {Create a new {\tt TVar\#} holding a specified initial value.}
with
 out_of_line  = True
 has_side_effects = True
```

According to https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/PrimOps, this is how primitives are defined so that the compiler knows about them.

Comment: `(# s2#, TVar tvar# #)` is an unboxed tuple. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html#unboxed-tuples

Comment: In `stg_newTVarzh` the last `zh` is the so-called z-encoding of `#`: this encoding generates a plain name usable by the linker/the ABI in all platform, removing funny characters like hash (#). I forgot where this encoding is actually defined. The `stg_` prefix is common to the whole GHC runtime, and stands for the spineless-tagless G-machine, an abstract machine to evaluate functional languages.

Comment: The z-encoding is detailed [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/SymbolNames), in case anyone is interested.

Comment: Great, thanks guys.  @chi, if you want to copy your comments into an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(# s2#, TVar tvar# #)` is an [unboxed tuple](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html#unboxed-tuples).

The name `stg_newTVarzh` is built from:

- The `stg_` prefix, which is common to the whole GHC runtime, and stands for the spineless-tagless G-machine, an abstract machine to evaluate functional languages;
- `newTVar` which is the first part of `newTVar#`;
- the final `zh`, which is the so-called [z-encoding](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/SymbolNames) of `#`: this encoding generates a plain name usable by the linker/the ABI in all platform, removing funny characters like hash (#).